# Comparing the contents of in two linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list, comparison

This is my first time working with linked lists and I've created both of my lists from two separate files and tokenized the data.

Now I need to compare the data and look for similarities, by that I mean the same data.
Such has list 1: 1, 3, dog and list 2: 1, dog, cat. Both have 1 and dog.

I am unsure how to approach this, and would love some tips, input, or hints.

Comment: This depends entirely on what you consider a "similarity".

Answer (score 1):

The code which compares two `Lists` only in case when their elements are comparable (i.e. implements `Comparable` interface).

This is parametrized so you can provide any type of List element which implements `Comparable` (`<T extends Comparable<T>>`)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.List;

public class ComparatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 6, 7}));
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 6}));

        final int result = new ComparatorTest().compareTo(list1, list2);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

    }

    <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareTo(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        int minLength = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
            final int compareValue = list1.get(i).compareTo(list2.get(i));
            if (compareValue != 0) {
                return compareValue; // They are already not equal
            }
        }
        if (list1.size() == list2.size()) {
            return 0; // They are equal
        } else if (list1.size() < list2.size()) {
            return -1; // list 1 is smaller
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```